# Multithreading Deadlock in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Please, can somebody explain me why this code is a deadlock. It seems that it should work properly. Please explain it in details. Thanks.

```
public class H extends Thread {
    String info = "";
    public H (String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public synchronized void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println(info);
                notify();
                wait();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          new H("0").start();
          new H("1").start();
    }
```

}

Comment: How exactly is it deadlocking? Is it printing both things but not terminating?

Comment: It prints 
0
1
And thats it stuck on deadlock

Answer (score 5):

Each thread synchronizes on `this` (via the `synchronized` keyword on the method) which is different for each of the two thread objects. They each call `notify` and `wait` but they don't interact since `this` is different. As such, on the first iteration, they both call `wait` and block forever because there is nobody to wake them up.

Here are some changes I made to make the code work as you intended. Notice the shared static fields that allow the threads to communicate:

```
public class Test extends Thread {
    String info = "";
    static final Object signal = new Object();
    static volatile String current = null;

    public Test (String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            synchronized(signal) {
                while (true) {                                  
                    while(current.equals(info))
                        signal.wait();
                    System.out.println(info);
                    current = info;
                    signal.notify();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test.current = "0";
        new Test("0").start();
        new Test("1").start();
    }
}
```

There are a few other notes on your original code I wanted to make:

- You should try to implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`. It gives you more flexibility that way.
- Don't swallow exceptions.

Comment: +1 because that's why they'd never finish, but that's not really deadlock. A deadlock is when two resources are both blocked waiting for the other to finish; this is just two resources waiting forever. It's a thread-parking version of `while(true) { }`.

Answer (score 3):

The `notify` and `wait` are called on the `Thread` objects which are different, so when a thread gets to `wait`, the other thread will not notify it, instead, each thread notifies itself.

The flow is pretty much (there might be interleaves):

1. ThreadA starts
2. ThreadA notifies for object that is waiting on ThreadA's lock
3. ThreadA waits on ThreadA's lock
4. ThreadB starts
5. ThreadB notifies for object that is waiting on ThreadB's lock
6. ThreadB waits on ThreadB's lock

Final states - both threads are waiting, no one to notify them.

Answer (score 1):

notify() only wakes up a thread that is currently waiting on the object. When you call notify(), no thread is waiting in either case. Then, when you call wait, you never have any code that notify()'s it. Basically, you can't notify a thread from the same thread, because it must be waiting. Try notifying them from the main thread after waiting some time and see what happens.

```
public class H extends Thread {
    String info = "";
    public H (String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public synchronized void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println(info);
                wait();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          H a = new H("0").start();
          H b = new H("1").start();
          Thread.sleep(1000);
          a.notify();
          b.notify();
    }
}
```

Note that neither thread notifies the other. waiting on an object only waits on it, not the class entirely.

TL;DR: notify() isn't doing anything and wait() creates the deadlock.